# foreach: Keep names

Tags: r, foreach

Is there a way to make foreach() return a named list/data.frame. E.g.

```
foo <- list(a = 1, b = 2)
bar <- foreach (x = foo) %do% { x * 2 }
```

returns `list(2, 4)`. I would want it to return `list(a = 2, b = 4)`.

Plus, is there a way to access the name from within the loop body?

(I'm not interested in a solution which assigns the names after the foreach loop.)

Regards

Comment: Not sure if `foreach` has the functionality for this. However you can change your loop to `foreach(i = seq_along(foo)) {x <- foo[[i]]; ...}` which will allow you to access the name of each element by `names(foo)[i]`

Comment: You could also use `x = Map(structure, .Data=lapply(foo, list), names=names(foo))` to get the names inside the loop, as though the loop were using `[` instead of `[[` to access the elements of `foo`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I was using your solution until I needed to use a nested foreach (with the `%:%` operator). I came up with this:

```
foo <- list(a = 1, b = 2)
bar <- foreach (x = foo, .final = function(x) setNames(x, names(foo))) %do% {
    x * 2
    }
```

The trick is to use the `.final` argument (which is a function applied once at the final result) to set the names. This is nicer because it doesn't use a temporary variable and is overall cleaner. It works with nested lists so that you can preserve the names accross several layers of the structure.

Note that this only works correctly if foreach has the argument `.inorder=T` (which is the default).

Comment: This seems to be the same as adding `names(bar) <- names(foo)` right after the `foreach` loop (without `.final`)?

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for your recommendations. This is what I came up with:

```
foo <- list(a = 1, b = 2)
bar <- foreach (x = foo, n = names(foo), .combine = c) %do% {
    rv <- list()
    rv[[n]] <- x * 2
    rv
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used to work with `foreach`, but having switched to `purrr` I am not looking back.

`purrr` provides a family of mapping functions which make working with named lists (and lists, and data.frames...) a complete breeze. All mapping operations preserve names.

```r
library("purrr")

foo <- list(a = 1, b = 2)
bar <- map(foo, ~ .x * 2)

# $a
# [1] 2
# $b
# [1] 4
```

Concise and clear, you can't really beat that.

> Plus, is there a way to access the name from within the loop body?

There sure is: `?imap`

```r
bar <- imap(foo, function(elem, name) {
    print(paste("Processing", name))
    elem * 2
})
```

Or anonymous style:

```r
bar <- imap(foo, ~ {print(paste("Processing", .y)) ; .x * 2})
```

Comment: This is nice, but `foreach` works in parallel while `purrr` doesn't. Also, while `furrr` offers a parallelized operation for `purrr`, `foreach` is still unique in its ability to use nested loops with `%:%`. So your `.final`  solution wins!